# How to remove \r, \n, \t from unicode strings in Python 2.7

Tags: python, unicode, html-escape-characters

I've got some scraped data filled with annoying escape characters:

```
{"website": "http://www.zebrawebworks.com/zebra/bluetavern/day.cfm?&year=2018&month=7&day=10", "headliner": ["\"Roda Vibe\" with the Tallahassee Choro Society"], "data": [" \r\n    ", "\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t", "\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t", "\r\n\t", "\r\n\t", "\r\n\t", "8:00 PM", "\r\n\t\r\n\tFEE:  $2 \u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 ", "\r\n\tEvery 2nd & 4th Tuesday of the month, the Choro Society returns to Blue Tavern with that subtly infectious Brazilian rhythm and beautiful melodies that will stay with you for days. The perfect antidote to Taylor Swift. $2 for musicians; tips appreciated. ", "\r\n\t", "\r\n\t\r\n\t", "\r\n\t", "\r\n\t", "\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t", "\r\n\t\r\n\t\t", "\r\n", "\r\n", "\r\n", "\r\n"]},
```

I'm trying to write a function to remove these characters, but neither of my two strategies are working:

```
    # strategy 1
    escapes = ''.join([chr(char) for char in range(1, 32)])
    table = {ord(char): None for char in escapes}
    for item in concert['data']:
        item = item.translate(table)
    # strategy 2
    for item in concert['data']:
        for char in item:
            char = char.replace("\r", "").replace("\t", "").replace("\n", "")
```

Why is my data still filled with the escape characters I've tried two different methods to remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
lst = ["aaa", "abc", "def"]

for x in lst:
    x = x.replace("a","z")

print(lst)  # ['aaa', 'abc', 'def']
```

It appears that the list was unchanged.  And it is (unchanged).  (Re)assigning to the variable used in your for loop (`x`) works *inside* the loop, but changes are never propagated back to `lst`.

Instead:

```
for (i,x) in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i] = x.replace("a","z")

print(lst)  # ['zzz', 'zbc', 'def']
```

Or

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = lst[i].replace("a","z")

print(lst)  # ['zzz', 'zbc', 'def']
```

**Edit**

Since you're using assignment (`x = ...`), you have to assign *back to the original list*, using something like `lst[i] = ...`.

With immutable types (which includes strings), this is really your only option.  `x.replace("a","z")` doesn't change `x`, it returns a new string with the specified replacements.

With *mutable* types (e.g. lists), you can perform in-place modification of the iterand (?) object -- the `x` in `for x in lst:`.

So something like the following will see the changes to `x` propagated to `lst`.

```
lst = [[1],[2],[3]]

for x in lst:
    x.append('added')  # Example of in-place modification

print(lst)  # [[1, 'added'], [2, 'added'], [3, 'added']]
```

As `x.append()` (unlike `str.replace()`) *does* change the `x` object.

Comment: Probably worth explaining that the first method only doesn't work because strings are immutable.  If there were objects in the list, you can do any sort of inplace modification and those would affect the list.

Comment: @user3483203 With assignment like that?

Comment: No, as that wouldn't be in-place

Comment: Okay just making sure, I'll add something to that effect.

Comment: Yea, I probably wasn't clear.  They are still accessing the actual element of the list using that method, but they can't modify it because you can't modify strings in place.

Comment: @user3483203 updated.  I hope it's clear (and fear it's a bit lacking).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this was exactly the explanation I needed.